# Passing a function with arguments as an argument in C++ (Arduino)

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino, arguments, arduino-c++

I'd like to write a sort-of wrapper function for my class... And i really dont know how to do that!

See, i want a, say, `run()`, function, to accept a function as an argument, thats the easy part.
The usage would be something like

```
void f() { }
void run(int (*func)) { 
//whatever code
func();
//whatever code
}
run(f);
```

That should just run the `f()` function, right?

But what if `f()` had required arguments? Say it was declared as `f(int i, int j)`, i would go along rewriting the `run()` function to separately accept those `int`s, and pass them to the `f()` function.

But I'd like to be able to pass Any function to `run()`, no matter how many arguments, or what type they are. Meaning, in the end, i'd like to get usage similar to what i would expect the hypothetical

```
void f() {int i, int j}
void v() {char* a, int size, int position}
void run(int (*func)) { 
//whatever code
func();
//whatever code
}
run(f(1, 2));
run(v(array, 1, 2));
```

to do. I know it looks dumb, but i think i'm getting my point across.

How would i do that?

Please remember that this is arduino-c++, so it might lack some stuff, but i do believe there are libraries that could make up for that...

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) then you can just use that:

```
void run(std::function<void()> fn) {
    // Use fn() to call the proxied function:
    fn();
}
```

You can invoke this function with a lambda:

```
run([]() { f(1, 2); });
```

Lambdas can even capture values from their enclosing scope:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
run([a, b]() { f(a, b); });
```

If you don't have `std::function` but you can use lambdas, you could make `run` a template function:

```
template <typename T>
void run(T const & fn) {
    fn();
}
```

Comment: Alright, i'll check if it works on my main project and report back!

Comment: Kay, i do not have std::function. The template solution seems to work, but i would also want the return type of the `fn` to be non void. A struct, infact. I know this isn't what i outlined in the post, but i thought that would be pretty straightforward... How would i make it so that i can do a ```returner=fn()``` in the `run()` function?

Comment: @TheFlazy Just pass in a lambda that returns something. In the run function you'll be able to assign the result. (I recommend `auto result = fn();` so you don't have to care about the actual return type.)

Comment: how would i do that? Using your syntax i passed a function that does return stuff, tried assigning something to that return, and it didnt really work... @cdhowie

Comment: @TheFlazy What does "didn't really work" mean? Can you show your code and any error messages?