# How i make function like void loop and void setup in arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

I want make function like void loop or void setup like arduino main function which that function can input another execution code.

```
unsigned long NOW;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  
  void doEvery(2){ //do Every 2 second
    //Put Code that Execute every 2 second
  }

  void doEvery(4){ //do Every 4 second
    //Put Code that Execute every 4 second
  }

}
```

How to declare/define function doEvery?
i think that function must contain

```
if(millis()-NOW>=EVERY){
NOW=millis();
//THE LINE CODE
}
```

Comment: Can't you define `doEvery` outside the loop and execute it in the loop?

Comment: am i defining ```doEvery``` ? i want use doEvery whenever i want in some case. So i dont need rewrite repeteadly with this code ```if(millis()-NOW>=EVERY){
NOW=millis();
//THE LINE CODE
}```

Comment: In arduino, `setup` and `loop` are special functions like `main` functions in normal C++ in the sense that they run without you having to call them when the program runs. You cannot replicate that. Also, you can't define a function in a function.

Comment: Technically, you could maybe replicate what you want to do with `std::function` and a lambda in normal C++ but I don't know enough about arduino to know if that is possible in arduino.

Comment: Try reading the Atmel application notes.  These toy functions are an C++/Arduino construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking [THIS](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay) as initial idea:

```
unsigned long previousMillis2 = 0, previousMillis100 = 0;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  //doEvery 2
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis2 >= 2) {
    previousMillis2 = currentMillis; //stores last execution's timestamp
    //CODE EVERY 2  millis
  }

  //doEvery 100
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis100 >= 100) {
    previousMillis100 = currentMillis; //stores last execution's timestamp
    //CODE EVERY 100  millis
  }
}
```

With this, you will use millis() to ask for how many millis passed since initialization of Arduino. Then you store last time you executed your code and compare how many time passed since it.
It's not a dynamic function for defining new intervals but if you only need a pair of it, you can code it easily.

**EDIT:**

If you need something more dynamic, you should use anonymous functions. [SEE THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265975/passing-a-function-with-arguments-as-an-argument-in-c-arduino) or [THIS](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=441516.0) The point here is **function as parameter**.

Comment: How about memory saving? It seems i need declare unsigned long every i want use that, btw i can do it even before you answer, but how about memory saving? What if i want perform diferent task? Okay now consider i want execution task A that do every 2 second so i must use variable ```previousmillis2000```, now after 1second i must execution task B that do every 2 second too but wait ```previousmilliss2000``` has been used, also it will make ram consumption you know ram in Arduino is too a bit. I ever make interface and giving 20% ram left and more unsigned long consume 32byte.

Answer (score 1):

I've made an animation library out of this for the WS2812 ledstrip:

https://github.com/laurijssen/ledstripanimator/blob/master/ledanim.c

The timing stuff that jabujavi describes happens in the UpdateFrame function where every animation in the list advances to the next frame after it's configured milliseconds.

```
class AnimList
{
  Animation *first = NULL;
  Adafruit_NeoPixel strip;

public:
  AnimList(int nleds) : strip(nleds, 9, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800)
  {
    strip.begin();
  }

  void UpdateFrame()
  {
    strip.clear();
    
    Animation **anim = &first;

    while (*anim)
    {
      if (millis() - (*anim)->last >= (*anim)->ms)
      {
        if (!(*anim)->UpdateFrame(strip))
        {
          *anim = (*anim)->next;
        }
        else
        {
          (*anim)->last = millis();
          anim = &(*anim)->next;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Now you just call AnimList::UpdateFrame as fast as possible inside loop()

```
void loop() {   
  list->UpdateFrame();
  list->Render();

  if (!list->Find(&r1))
  {
    r1 = Rain (rand() % NUMLEDS, rand() % NUMLEDS, {BRIGHTNESS, 0, 15 }) ;
    list->AddFirst(&r1);
  } 
}
```

*edit*

So if you want to execute code every 2 seconds you create a class which inherits from Animation and override Updateframe. Then put ms variable at the time you want to pass between frames.
Of course remove all Adafruit and animation references if you just want a task based lib.

```
class TaskA : public Task
{
public:
  TaskA() { ms = 2000; }

  bool UpdateFrame()
  {    
    Serial.println("2 seconds passed");
    
    return true;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  }
  
};

TaskA t;

void setup()
{
  list->AddTask(&t);
}

void loop()
{
  list->UpdateTasks();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain where i should put task A (line code A) that do every 2second or 3second or whatever second i want on your code?